# Report extra information from a test_that block when failing

Tags: r, testing, testthat

I want to `cat()` some information to the console in the case a test fails (I'm getting confident this won't happen but I can't prove it wont) so I can investigate the issue.

Now I have code that is approximately like this:

```
testthat::test_that('Maybe fails', {
  seed <- as.integer(Sys.time())
  set.seed(seed)
  
  testthat::expect_true(maybe_fails(runif(100L)))
  testthat::expect_equal(long_vector(runif(100L)), target, tol = 1e-8)

  if (failed()) {
    cat('seed: ', seed, '\n')
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, `failed()` doesn't exist.

Return values of `expect_*()` don't seem useful, they just return the actual argument.

I'm considering to just check again using `all.equal()` but that is a pretty ugly duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `cat`, you could use the `info` argument managed by `testthat` and its `reporters` for all `expect` functions ([argument kept for compatibility reasons](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/expect.html)):

```r
library(testthat)

testthat::test_that("Some tests",{
  
  testthat::expect_equal(1,2,info=paste('Test 1 failed at',Sys.time()))
  testthat::expect_equal(1,1,info=paste('Test 2 failed at',sys.time()))

})
#> -- Failure (<text>:5:3): Some tests --------------------------------------------
#> 1 not equal to 2.
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 1 - 2 == -1
#> Test 1 failed at 2021-03-03 17:25:37
```

Comment: Did you mention  `<<-` in the example you provided in your question?

Comment: How do you run the test? I get the same result even with `<<-` in interactive mode

Comment: Sorry, my mistake : the example I provided  is too simple )-:

Comment: TryCatch would work if this is suitable for you : `tryCatch(testthat::expect_equal(1,2),error = function(e) {cat('test')})`

Comment: Yes correct, this is what I just figured out :-). Quite heavy but does the job

Comment: Not yet fully satisfied with `stop(e)` because looks like further tests are cancelled by this error.

Comment: This reminds me of the `info` argument : see my edit!

Comment: Excellent solution!